# Bulk-Edit in external lists (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, external-list, bulk

I try to provide bulk editing for external lists. 
I heard that the datasheet view is a convenient tool, but it is not enabled for external lists. Is there any way to get an easy, user-friendly bulk editing going?